# Integrals considering partitions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

If f(x) < g(x) for all $x \in [a,b]$, then can we say that inf(U(P,f)) will be less than inf(U(P,g))?

Why or why not is this correct ?
Here U(P,f) represents upper riemann sum of f considered over partition P.

Comment: In general you will have $\inf U(P, f) \leq \inf U(P, g) $ but if in addition it is known that $f, g$ are Riemann integrable then we can show with some effort that $\inf U(P, f) <\inf U(P, g) $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Note that $\inf_PU(P,f)$ is a lower bound for $U(P,g)$ and $\inf_PU(P,g)$ is the ***greatest*** lower bound

Comment: Please be more specific I am new to this and have very little idea on how this works.

Comment: First, do you understand why for any partition $P$, the upper sums satisfy $U(P,f) \leqslant U(P,g)$

Comment: On any subinterval $I_j = [x_{j-1},x_j]$ of partition $P$,we have $f(x) < g(x).$  Hence, $\sup_{x \in I_j} f(x) \leqslant \sup_{x \in I_j} g(x)$, which implies $U(P,f) \leqslant U(P,g)$.  Taking the infimum of both sides we get the desired result.